# NestJS gRPC empty return

Tags: nestjs, grpc

I am learning something new with NestJS and gRPC. I'm just running into a problem. I have created an auth microservice and a gateway but I get an empty response back.

The gateway and the microservice are triggered. but I get an empty object back. If I do hardcode in the gateway without gRPC then it works. Does anyone know what I've forgotten?

**Gateway**

```
import { Body, Controller, OnModuleInit, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Client, ClientGrpc } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { authOptions } from 'src/grpc.options';
import { AuthService } from './grpc.interface';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController implements OnModuleInit {
    @Client(authOptions)
    private client: ClientGrpc;

    private authService: AuthService;

    onModuleInit() {
        this.authService = this.client.getService<AuthService>('AuthService');
    }

    @Post('login')
    async login(@Body('username') username: string, @Body('password') password: string)
    {
        return this.authService.login({ username, password });
    }
}
```

**Auth Microservice**

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';

interface LoginArgs {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

interface LoginReturn {
    access_token: string;
}

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {

    @GrpcMethod('AuthService', 'Login')
    login(data: LoginArgs, metadata: any): LoginReturn
    {
        return {
            access_token: '123',
        }
    }

}
```

**Proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package auth;

service AuthService {
    rpc Login (LoginArgs) returns (LoginReturn);
}

message LoginArgs {
    string username = 1;
    string password = 2;
}

message LoginReturn {
    string access_token = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gRPC Client does not send fields when field name contains underscore.

You should delete all underscores from **access_token** and then works.

Or add the following **keepCase: true**  to the connection option (as [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4917#issuecomment-645398553) mentioned)

```js
app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      package: 'test',
      protoPath: 'path/to/proto',
      loader: { keepCase: true },
    },
  });
```